# IF-condition on attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I am creating a simple XML schema for chess game.
I don't want pieces that have not been taken to be duplicated, so I used unique.
But, the problem is pieces that have been taken and the pieces that have taken those taken pieces are duplicated.
So, I want to use if statement. For example, if (taken=="no") then apply the unique; if (taken=="yes"), don't care about unique

Here's my xsd code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- Type Definitions -->
  <xs:simpleType name="pieceSymbolType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="P|p|R|r|N|n|B|b|K|k|Q|q" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="pieceNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="pawn|rook|knight|bishop|king|queen" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="piecePositionRangeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="11" />
      <xs:maxInclusive value="88" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="playerNameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="BLACK|white" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="takenPieceType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="yes|no" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="myChess">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="player" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="pieces">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="piece" minOccurs="16" maxOccurs="16">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="pieceNameType" use="optional" />
                        <xs:attribute name="position" type="piecePositionRangeType" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="symbol" type="pieceSymbolType"  use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="taken" type="takenPieceType" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:unique name="UniquePiecePosition">
                  <xs:selector xpath="piece" />
                  <xs:field xpath="@position" />
                </xs:unique>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="playerNameType"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible within a single type of element. In other words if you need to filter on an attribute value you have to use different element name. Here is how you can do it (I have simplified the code a bit).

```
<xs:element name="myChess">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="pieceType1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="test1" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:string" fixed="no" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="pieceType2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="test1" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="taken" type="xs:string" fixed="yes" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eranda for the help. I applied your strategy to my project, and it worked.

Comment: @PhillipHG mark this as answered so that others may use the same.